# Guarantee for closest random point on a sphere

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, spheres

Let $v \in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ be a fixed point on a sphere, and $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n \sim Unif(\mathbb{S}^{d-1})$ which are i.i.d.

How large $n$ can guarantee that, with probability $1-\delta$, $\exists i$ such that $\|v-X_i \|\leq \epsilon$?

I think sufficiently many samples could do this, but I don't know how to calculate.

What about the case when $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n \sim N(0,1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $d(u,x)$ is the distance between $u$ and $x$, then
$$
\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{d(u,X_i)>\epsilon\}\right)=[\mathsf{P}(d(u,X_1)>\epsilon)]^n=\left[\frac{|\{x\in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}:d(u,x)>\epsilon\}|}{|\mathbb{S}^{d-1}|}\right]^n.
$$
(Here $|\cdot|$ denotes area.)

Comment: Thanks for your great idea! Now any estimate about the area of that local area would finish the thing....... is there any nice bound for that local area? I think when $\epsilon$ is quite small, we can say that the small area will be close to $0.5|S^{d-2}|$....... am I right?

Comment: @ForgotEverything How do you measure the distance between $u$ and each $X_i$ exactly?

Comment: Usual $l_2$ norm. $\|a\|=\sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots + a_d^2}$. Now I can't edit my comment above, but it seems like $|\{ x\in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}: d(u,x)\leq \epsilon\}| \leq vol (B_{\epsilon}^{d-2} )$ where $B_{\epsilon}^{d-2}$ is a $d-2$ dimensional ball with radius $\epsilon$ (it's just my hunch, and I am trying to prove it)

Comment: @ForgotEverything So, it is the distance in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and not the geodesic distance on $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$.

Comment: Exactly. Since I think it is hard to calculate the exact area of $|\{x \in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}:d(u,x)<\epsilon\}|$ (and the result might be messy), I am looking for a nice upper bound for that area.

Comment: @ForgotEverything You can actually calculate the area of the corresponding hyperspherical cap. See [this paper](http://docsdrive.com/pdfs/ansinet/ajms/2011/66-70.pdf) for details.